# How to split array and store each value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have array like below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png
    [1] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png
    [2] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911571.png
)
```

I want to split above array and each key value has to stored in localStorage like `'front'=> array[0],'back'=>array[1],'side'=>array[0]`.

How to achieve this. ?

Comment: Please define "splitting an array".

Comment: And from where front, back, side keys are coming?

Comment: You can use directly how you want *'front'=> array[0],'back'=>array[1],'side'=>array[0].* like this.

Comment: Is the array present in javascript or in php ?

Comment: 0,1 and 2 I should make front, back and side and values to be stored in local storage with their respective keys.

Comment: Ah ... You want to convert the array to an object, and have those keys instead of indices?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your array is in **JAVASCRIPT**, you can access to the array elements directly, so you can call the localStorage function directly...

   ```
   var yourArray = [
       'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png',
       'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png',
       'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911571.png'
   ];

   localStorage.setItem('front',yourArray[0]);
   localStorage.setItem('back',yourArray[1]);
   localStorage.setItem('side',yourArray[2]);
   ```
2. If your array is in **PHP**, you'll have to add a `<script>` element...

   ```
   <?php
   $yourarray = array(
       "http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png",
       "http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png",
       "http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911571.png"
   );
   ?>

   <script>
     localStorage.setItem('front','<?=$yourarray[0]?>');
     localStorage.setItem('back','<?=$yourarray[1]?>');
     localStorage.setItem('side','<?=$yourarray[2]?>');
   </script>
   ```

Comment: It is storing only first character like front=>r , back=> A, side=>r

Comment: `yourArray` is the variable where you have your array with the three URL's (you don't show it's name in the question, so I've used that name as an example). I've edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Wait... is it a PHP array or a Javascript array?

Answer (score 0):

you can have separate script (test.php) and have a json out as below

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(
    0 => 'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png',
    1 => 'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911570.png',
    2 => 'http://192.168.1.156/dutees_dev/image/catalog/tmprgbimages/1508911571.png'
);

$arr2 = array('front'=>'', 'back'=>'', 'side'=>'');


// assign values from array 1 to array 2
$arr2['front'] = $arr1[0];
$arr2['back'] = $arr1[1];
$arr2['side'] = $arr1[2];


echo json_encode($arr2);
```

then from javascript you can access this object as follows and store it in local storage

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.get("test.php", function (data, status) {

                    var out = JSON.parse(data);

                    // Store in local storage
                    localStorage.setItem("frontElem", out.front);
                    localStorage.setItem("backElem", out.back);
                    localStorage.setItem("sideElem", out.side);

                    var side = localStorage.getItem("sideElem", out.side);
                    console.log(side)

                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Explain how he can save that to the localStorage object. Cuse now he only has an array, without knowing what to do with it. All it does in the end is printing the array. How can he move this to javascript and save it?

Comment: @moha kumar you can have a php which output your array as a json and you can get it in your javascript. please check my edit above